# Android Webview 405 error

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, android-webview, http-status-code-405

I'm having a bit of a rough time with Android webview.

For some reason my webview has stopped working. I'm currently running into a 405 Method Not Allowed error with the following:

```
Code:Method Not Allowed

Method: POST

ResourceType: OBJECT

RequestId: FF1CD99DD13F1E454

HostId: <some very long number>
```

The webview as you'd expect is just displaying a site, which you can link to here:

http://nodex.com.s3-website-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/

Up until today it was working fine, however the graph is now not showing now and whenever a search term is entered it is coming back with this 405 error, which seems strange, since the web page is the one executing the post and webview is just providing the interface.

Should also mention the web app is connecting to API gateway on AWS and CORS is turned on.

Very stripped back code from Android is here:

```
package com.example.gaz.nodex_1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
        wv.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
        WebSettings webSettings = wv.getSettings();
        webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        wv.loadUrl("http://nodex.com.s3-website-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/");

    }

}
```

Comment: read http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E405.html

Comment: Yep thanks, but that doesn't explain anything about by webview would be encountering the 405 while the web page itself functions correctly. The web page itself is able to make the connection to the API, but when loaded through webview, it throws the error. Any suggestion on how I can trace it back further?